# Check if a certain application is installed via registry problem?

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

I'm trying to check if certain programs are installed using the registry and I hit a problem, Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I don't know why .. can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

This is the code I'm using

```
public static bool checkInstalled(string c_name)
    {
        string displayName;

        string registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey);
        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (RegistryKey subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames().Select(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName)))
            {
                displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                if (displayName != null && displayName.Contains(c_name))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            key.Close();
        }

        registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey);
        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (RegistryKey subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames().Select(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName)))
            {
                displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                if (displayName != null && displayName.Contains(c_name))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            key.Close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and I just call it by

```
if (checkInstalled("XXXXX"))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

it doesn't always work .. for example if I try to check for `"Riot Vanguard"` it will not work and it will return false even if it's installed. and here is the [regkey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Vdh.png) for it.

Comment: Looks fine at first sight. Did you Debug your program?

Comment: You know that `"Riot Vanguard` != `Riot Vanguard` and the carachter `"` shouldn't be there, it is only a visual aid to show it is a string, but the actual value is without the `"`.

Comment: I did and it just can't find it for some reason .. I call the function multiple times for different app check and it works on some of them and others it just don't !

Comment: You may want to read this aswell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974038/reading-64bit-registry-from-a-32bit-application

Comment: yeah I just miss typed I meant "Riot Vanguard" as in if (checkInstalled("Riot Vanguard")) ..
@RandRandom

Comment: Is your application running as 64 bit or as 32 bit?

Comment: as 64 bit
@KlausGütter

Comment: "just miss typed" - you can [edit] your question to correct it

Answer (score 0):

I know that's a long shot and might not matter, but whenever I have problems in code that uses collections created with Linq I like to put `.ToList()` at the end to make sure that the whole query executes before proceeding (in your case I mean collections in the `foreach` loops)