# Settings.Default doesn't update data after Reload()

Tags: c#, asp.net

After changing the value of `ApplicationSettings` in `web.config`, the data of `Settings.Default` doesn't update.

I try to call

```
Settings.Default.Reload();
```

but it does not work.

Values update only after I open project settings in Visual Studio.
 How can I update `Settings.Default` values in run-time? Is this possible?

**Solved**
Alright, values are updated! The problem was that I tried to get the value from `Settings.Default.Properties["Key"].DefaultValue`, which means to get the default value that is stored in `settings.settings`. To get the updated value, you must use `Settings.Default.Key` property.

Comment: Does that help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335931/save-and-reload-app-configapplicationsettings-at-runtime

Comment: It helped me save change in web.conf. But after this change Settings.Default.SomeProperty have old value (because it save in settings.setting file). I want to update this value, but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Settings.Default.Reload() inside of an initialize/formLoad event