# How can I save connection string at run time in App.config file?

Tags: c#, vb.net, app-config, vb.net-2010

I tried to save the connection string in the App.confing file at the run time, then I opened the file during the application while it was running, and I found the connection string had been saved in the file, but after I closed the application the connection string had been deleted automatically.

Can you help me to keep the connection string in the app.config file?
I added two textboxes to the form (txtServer and txtDatabase) and one button to connect to database when the user click it.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim strConnectionStringName As String = "con"
        Dim Con As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder("Data Source=")
        Con.Append(txtServer.Text)
        Con.Append(";Initial Catalog=")
        Con.Append(txtDatabase.Text)
        Con.Append(";Integrated Security=SSPI;")
        Con.Append("User ID=username; Password=xyz;")

        Dim ConStringSettings As New ConnectionStringSettings(strConnectionStringName, Con.ToString)
        Dim Config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        AddAndSaveOneConnectionStringSettings(Config, ConStringSettings)

        Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con").ToString() & _
            "This is invalid connection", "Incorrect server/Database.")
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub AddAndSaveOneConnectionStringSettings(ByVal Config As Configuration, _
            ByVal ConStringSettings As ConnectionStringSettings)
    Dim ConStringsSection As ConnectionStringsSection = Config.ConnectionStrings
    ConStringsSection.ConnectionStrings.Add(ConStringSettings)
    Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal)
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings")
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you only need to specify a force save :

```
ConStringsSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = True
```

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335931/save-and-reload-app-configapplicationsettings-at-runtime) for more information .

Comment: I tried your solution but nothing changed, the connection string still deleted from the app.config file after closing the application.