# Pass Values BAck to my Parent form through COnfig--Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a scenario where we were using windows application and we were taking some of the values from our App config file.

These values were being Updated in my Constructor Itself.

Example:if i have Form1,I was taking the values in like below

```
public form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        xs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xyx"].ToString();

    }
```

Now we have added one Button in our Application on clicking that it would redirect to another form which have the facility to Update my config file and save it.
Now after it saved it my Form1 has to take the Updated Config values. I tried many ways but didnt work can you Please help me with this?

Thanks,
SUjith.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save and reload app.config(applicationSettings) at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335931/save-and-reload-app-configapplicationsettings-at-runtime)