# When does WCF load the values from app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config

I'm having a bit of trouble with WCF and an *on-boot* generated `app.config`.

This is a WPF app that consumes a WCF service. If the app is started without an `app.config` it will create one from an embedded resource. This freshly created `app.config` contains the WCF configuration options, like the binding. But when I try to create a channel, I get an exception: `Could not find endpoint element with name 'WSHttpBinding_IService`. If I restart the application with the newly created `app.config` everything works as expected.

From what I can understand, WCF has already loaded the values from the missing `app.config` before I create the new one. Even though there are no calls to any WCF functionality by then. The app use (very old) Caliburn.Micro and Autofac, and create the new `app.config` in the constructor in the `ApplicationBootstrapper`:

```cs
class ApplicationBootStrapper : TypedAutofacBootStrapper<MainViewModel>
{
    public ApplicationBootStrapper() : base()
    {
        MakeSureConfigFileExists();
    }

    // The rest of my code
}
```

Any tips to how I can get WCF to re-read the `app.config`?

**Edit:**
*It might be a duplicate, but I haven't managed to refresh the section `system.serviceModel`.*

I have tried:

```cs
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("system.serviceModel");
```

**Edit 2:**
*I've since moved the code that generate the missing `app.config` so that it's run in the very beginning of `OnStartup` in the bootstrapper class:*

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    MakeSureConfigFileExists();

    // The rest of my code
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save and reload app.config(applicationSettings) at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335931/save-and-reload-app-configapplicationsettings-at-runtime)

Comment: The name of config file in runtime should be not app.config, but rather exe_file_name.exe.config. Also configuration file is not required for WCF -- if you have it as resource, you probably can do all configuration from code.

Comment: @the_joric yes, I know, and it is. Hence _"If I restart the application with the newly created app.config everything works as expected."_

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, which is to spawn a new process where i start the app again, and then quit the original one. This works fine, but seems a bit unnecessary.