# C# console app save last runtime before closing

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing a C# console application in .Net Framework 4.6.1, Visual Studio 2013, Windows 10 x64. I want to save last runtime timestamp in the `Properties.Settings.Default.LastRuntime` property settings every time when the application closes. It should work when user closes it by clicking on close [X] button, `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+Break`, windows shutdown, logoff events. Here is my code. Nothing seems to be working. `LastRuntime` property is not updating:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        string lrt = Properties.Settings.Default.LastRuntime;
        Console.Write(lrt);
        Console.ReadLine();
        handler = new ConsoleEventDelegate(ConsoleEventCallback);
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, true);
    }

    // Handle application termination
    static bool ConsoleEventCallback(int eventType)
    {
        // Termination events: Ctrl+C = 0, Ctrl+Break = 1, Close/Cancel = 2, Logoff = 5, Shutdown = 6
        if (new[] { 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 }.Contains(eventType))
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.LastRuntime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'hh':'mm':'ss");
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        return false;
    }
    static ConsoleEventDelegate handler;
    private delegate bool ConsoleEventDelegate(int eventType);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleEventDelegate callback, bool add);
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things going on here with a lot of SO posts relating to the matter, so I'll try to summarize for you:

1. [Application Settings scope - user vs application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145955/application-settings-scope-user-vs-application)

> In short, application scoped settings can't be changed at runtime while user scoped
> settings are designed be read/written at runtime.
>
> Use user scoped settings

2. [Why are my application settings not getting persisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054422/why-are-my-application-settings-not-getting-persisted) (assuming you already use user settings)

> If you have your Assembly info set to automatically generate any version numbers (1.0.*), then every time you debug your app the version number will be different, and so will be creating a new file every time.
>
> If this is the case you will need to perform an upgrade on the settings file:
>
> `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade()`

3. [C# Settings.Default.Save() not saving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881415/c-sharp-settings-default-save-not-saving) To make sure the change is depicted in your code (if not restarting)

> You need to call `Default.Reload` after calling the Save method:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture it when the window closes, you can use the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` event

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(ConsoleExit);           
    }

    private static void ConsoleExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.LastRuntime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'hh':'mm':'ss");
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```