# Property of indexer cannot be assigned to , it's read only. Can't save settings

Tags: c#, textbox, settings, readonly

Today I continue to work with **TextBox1_LastValue**.
In [MSDN manuals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) is everything awesome, as always. I followed those instructions and had got a fail like shown below. This is in scopes of FormClosed event handler.
How to do that writeable (not readonly)?

[image]

this is **textBox1_LastValue** itself.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which tutorial you followed?

Comment: You can't set application-scope settings, only user-scope settings.

Comment: @Msorich, What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to write into parameter 'textBox1_LastValue' last inputted textBox value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make this setting user- instead of application-scope. Then it's not readonly and you can save it.

[How do I get around application scope settings being read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687321/how-do-i-get-around-application-scope-settings-being-read-only)

Comment: I considered that I needed app settings, not user. OK, first I'll try 'user' variant. We'll see... Yeahhh, I've got read of a fail, however last value is still not retaining...(((