# .net desktop app - how do store/change application settings or connection strings?

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, desktop-application, application-settings

I need to give the user the ability to change application settings, in this case the location for the application database.  I noticed that Application Settings are read only at run time, but this needs to be application-wide, not user-specific.  How do I persist an application-wide connection string in windows.forms that is changeable at runtime?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-application

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set()
```

Also

[ConnectionStringSettings.ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings.connectionstring.aspx)

Can be set too.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("test","tada");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal, true);
```

Comment: -1: Only for user-level stuff, and you dont want to write to Progrm Files directory

Comment: -1 removed in light of edit - but if you are going this route, you should definitely not be writing beside the EXE or in the EXE's .config file - you should be writing to the AppSettings directory

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a direct way in the framework using the newer Settings classes - you can save user-level settings with the Settings support, *but not application/machine level*. Easiest way is to XmlSerialize a class and store it in a directory that *is* shared between all users with write acccess when they are running un-elevated such as the Public Documents folder (the program directory shouldnt be written to), e.g.. `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`

EDIT: Yes, the old appSettings mechanism has a way of writing, but that's bad news - the newer Settings stuff omits this facility as it is bad news for lots of reasons to try to write to config files in Program Files

Comment: That would be user-wide, not application-wide, no?

Comment: @Blue Raja - Danny Pflughoeft: That's what the text of my answer said. I added the italicised section just now to make it 100% clear, HTH...

Comment: I meant that the `%AppData%` directory is user-wide, not application-wide - is that the same thing as the *"AppSettings directory"*?

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: Yes, having actually read my answer, I see it avoids the question nicely in that it doesnt say *where* to /actually/ put it - a common documents folder is the answer, and is much better than e.g. adjusting the permissions on a Program Files sub directory or allowing onself to be redirected via virtualization to ProgramData