# Read config file using XMl reader

Tags: c#, xml, web-config, drop-down-menu

I have a bunch of key in AppSettings section of my web.config file. I want to read the key and values of those app settings using XML reader technique and populate them in the list box.

Comment: You could do that, but it would be easier to simply use a configuration manager and iterate through all the app settings keys.  Or use a Properties file and have them all located in a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way is to retrive webconfig values is to use System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

To retrive values of webconfig from xml reader:

```
private void loadConfig()
        {

            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load( Server.MapPath("~/") + "web.config");
            XmlNode  xnodes = xdoc.SelectSingleNode ("/configuration/appSettings");

                foreach (XmlNode xnn in xnodes .ChildNodes)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(xnn.Attributes[0].Value  + " = " + xnn.Attributes[1].Value );
                }              

        }
```

Reference:http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2010/10/read-config-file-using-xml-reader.html

Comment: This way is better than ConfigurationManager.AppSettings because you can have whatever file name and path that you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can just get a reference to the AppSettings NameValueCollection and iterate as follows:

```
NameValueCollection settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

foreach (string key in settings.AllKeys)
{
   string value = settings[key];
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for ur help. it did work for me. I would also like to savevalues to config file is there anyway that i can do that

Comment: Take a look at this so post, else you can create a custom config section and save that way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-pratice-to-save-application-settings-in-windows-application