# Config file reading

Tags: c#, xml, config

I am trying to retrieve some information from a .config file. I need to search for specific tags and get the attributes in those tags. For example in application tag i need to get the attribute path. I don't need any other information from the .config file. I was just going through XmlTextReader but then realised i need a config file and don't know if it is the right way.

Comment: Is it a .net Config file? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Are you looking for [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

Comment: Guys it is a .config file. Ok here is the file i need to read ..
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

i need to pull out only data withing the <sites> and </sites>

Comment: I am using this code now to get the content within the sites tag, how do i filter down to get info of the site tag that lies withing sites tag ?

XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(@"\\rabaro-dtp2\C$\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config");


            
            while (xtr.Read())
            {
                // Do some work here on the data.
                if (xtr.Name.Equals("sites"))
                {
                    
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [`Using the File attribute of the appSettings element of a .NET config file`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/appsettings_fileattribute.aspx)

And you **must** read this great article about [`using configuration file in .NET`](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c7987__1/Using-Application-Configuration-Files-in-NET.htm)

Also found [Read config file using XMl reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868179/read-config-file-using-xml-reader)

Answer (score 2):

The right way is using a [ConfigurationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.aspx) descendant. For each section in app.config / web.config you have a specific class to manage that section.
If you need to modify the app.config / web.config file, you can use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class.