# How to save application settings to file?

Tags: .net, application-settings

I have simple application. To be more specific this is Visual Studio Addin.
Client needs to specify several settings (string, int, decimal etc)

I need to be able to load it at starup time and save if changed.

Let's say for simplicity I have all settings in one class AppSettings.

I can of course use DataContractSerializer to serialize/deserialize AppSettings but
I think there must be some standard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Application Settings from Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(APPLICATIONSETTINGSOVERVIEW);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22)&rd=true

You can use it like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.DumpHeader = dumpHeader;
Properties.Settings.Default.DumpFooter = dumpFooter;

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

And loading works similar. But you have to define a .settings file first. It's from the WPF Framework, not sure if it works for WinForms too.

Similar question with a similar answer:
[Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-application)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a huge fan of **flat file storage** myself, for example INI files. An article with example code on how to use INI files with .NET can be found [here](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3287991).

Comment: It assumes extra work - interop. INI files are not supported by .NET

Comment: Yes, because Microsoft is _trying_ to move away from them. I'm not sure on how the information is stored, but some sites suggest it's XML. I truly detest XML. It's a markup language FFS!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Addin is specific case. In this case we can distribute only a .dll file which contain add in code and some .xml with Add-in definition if you want to use [standard installation Add-In package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246580%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). When I had such problem I try to resolve it with Windows registry. You can find a lot of examples how to deal with Windows registry in c#.