# How should I store and manage user settings

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have a windows service whose settings are stored in an ini file in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\company\product and handled by Nini. Now I will write a similar application and look at if I can do a better solution this time. How do you want me to save all program settings. Where should the file be saved? Which tool should I use for handling the file?

The settings should be easily changed by the customer directly in the file. It must be a fix directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-application)

Comment: Do you want to write settings from the Service?

Comment: @Henk Holterman - No, the service do not change the settings

Comment: Is it going to be per login basis ?

Comment: @Kumar - No, it is per application basis

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Isolated Storage](http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/forms/usersettings.html). [Or see for other alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-application)

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's not predefined in wish directory settings are saved in. I have to write in the documentation exact path to the settings file.

Comment: I think you can create an `IsolatedStorageFileStream CreateFile(
 string path
)` else you need see for different approach.

Comment: IsolatedStorage is intended for low-privilege software, usually not the case for a Service. And not user editable.

Comment: As poster said `Now I will write a similar application`, is it going to be a service again or some kind of non service application ?

Comment: The location of IsolatedStorage also depends on the particular assembly and changes with each build of the application (thereby becoming "isolated"). The `IsolatedStorageFileStream.CreateFile(string)` method takes a relative path within the isolated foulder.

Comment: Yeah it takes relative path, just figured it out :)

Comment: @Kumar - The new application is a windows service

Comment: Isolated Storage encapsulates the directory from the user - which doesn't meet this requirement: The settings should be easily changed by the customer directly in the file.