# How I can change the applicationSettings in my web.config via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config, application-settings

I want to change the web.config via C#.

My Web.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!--
      Weitere Informationen zum Konfigurieren der ASP.NET-Anwendung finden Sie unter
      "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433"
      -->

    <configuration>
        <configSections>
            ...
        </configSections>
        <system.web>
            ...
        </system.web>

        <applicationSettings>
            <AdminTest.Properties.Settings>
                <setting name="AD_Admin" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>GastzugangAdmin</value>
                </setting>
                <setting name="AD_User" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>GastzugangUser</value>
                </setting>
            </AdminTest.Properties.Settings>
        </applicationSettings>
    </configuration>
```

With string `ADAdmin = Properties.Settings.Default.AD_Admin;` can I get the value from th `web.config` but I don't know how I can overwrite this. I try this.

```
protected void btnCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string con = txtCon.Text;

            try
            {
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("AD_Admin", con);
                Settings.Default.Save();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
```

But I doesn't work.

Comment: You want updating a value in memory-loaded settings or in the web.config file?

Comment: I suggest moving user-changable settings into the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274829/configurationmanager-appsettings-how-to-modify-and-save

Answer (score 0):

There is configuration API in .NET Fx for modifying the configuration, you can use the same. For example, check [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx)

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");
config.AppSettings["xyz"] = value;
config.Save();
```

Note that your web application would be restarted whenever you save the config.

Comment: The Acces to System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.this[System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty] don't work because of securitylevel :(

Comment: @Tarasov, try `config.AppSettings.Settings["xyz"] = value`. BTW, the user account under which your code is running also need read/write permission on web.config file.