# Possible to use Properties.Settings in the Web.config of a ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to set some values in the `Web.config` file via the `Properties.Settings.Default...` settings in a asp.net project?

EDIT: I know how to create the settings. but my question is: can I use them directly inside the XML of the webConfig. e.g. I devine a setting called database and then I use this variable inside the connection string in the web.config

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274829/configurationmanager-appsettings-how-to-modify-and-save

Comment: its not a duplicate. I know how to create the settings. but my question is: can I use them directly inside the XML of the webConfig. e.g. I devine a setting called database and then I use this variable inside the connection string in the web.config