# How to retrieve a variable in memory from a WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a WPF application, when the app runs I need to store a variable in a shared memory.
When the app is being closed and successively restart I need to get the variable previously stored. I need a simple solution, I would avoid using a text file saved in some place.
If the machine is restarted I do now need to get that variable.

Any idea what are my option?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, is there any reason why you can't save to a text file? It would most likely be a lot more easier/simple.

Comment: Why can't you save it in appsettings ?

Comment: @CodeWeed: isn't appsettings basically a text file? (Not that I know why that's a bad idea, but still...)  GibboK: if you want to persist data after your app is shut down then you have to to save it 8somewhere* - that's going to be either a file or perhaps the registry. Why don't you want to use a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use your Settings file to save properties between application sessions.

For more information see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) and note the **Saving User Settings at Run Time** section. It technically is "saved" to a file, but in a much dev-friendly manner.

Edit: That is a link for VS2005, oops! Use [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) and refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274829/configurationmanager-appsettings-how-to-modify-and-save) when saving for newer apps.

Comment: @eran I know the title suggests that ... but the detail is about persisting across machine restarts.

Comment: yes i get that , it just seemed obvious that he meant that as an alternative to writing to any files , where he said text file he probably meant any file

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to avoid writing/reading files, you could use the `Registry`.