# Can't modify app.config file with no error

Tags: c#, app-config, appsettings

I'm struggling with trying to modify the appSettings part of the app.config file of my application. However I'm not receiving any error/exception and I can read values without any problem.
Here is how I tried to set values :

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("DaysLeft", Days.Text.ToString());
//    
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["DaysLeft"].Value = Days.Text.ToString();
//when I debug the app, I notice that the value is changed in the previous line
```

The app.config file isn't being modified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274829/configurationmanager-appsettings-how-to-modify-and-save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = 
         ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["DaysLeft"].Value = Days.Text.ToString();
config.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your changes

```
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Also, if you want to reload the app.config

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```