# Replace, not add the value in .config file

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Service written, and want to modify it's config file. I have an app in the same solution for this:

```
 private ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
 map.ExeConfigFilename = @"pathToMyWSConfigFile";
```

and then I do:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("ServerPath", "test replace ");

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

However this simply adds another value to the ServerPath key in config file, and I want to replace it, so that there is always only one value there. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings - How to modify and save?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274829/configurationmanager-appsettings-how-to-modify-and-save)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149556/app-config-change-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a setting, simply use the Settings indexer.

```
config.AppSettings.Settings["ServerPath"].Value = "test replace";
```