# Connection Strings in different .NET versions config

Tags: c#, .net, config

I'm building a Windows Service in .NET 8 to monitor resources. This service references an old .NET Framework 4.6.1 project. I do not have the time or resources to rewrite the functionality in .NET 8.

The problem is the old project attempts to retrieve connection strings via the ConfigurationManager. Because we are using appsettings.json in the .NET 8 project, the old project triggers a null pointer exception.

Short of dependency injection or passing the connection as a parameter, is it possible to solve the config null pointer issue in a simple way?

Comment: Without showing us the relevant code, the people can only guess

Comment: Provide the equivalent configuration in XML format?  Web.config.

Comment: "I do not have the time or resources to rewrite the functionality in .NET 8" Why rewrite? In most cases, that's just an update of the project file and it should work just fine.

Comment: I had similair problem at one of my projects, the way my team solved it was get instance of `IConfiguration` which was populated by `appsettings.json`, then we used `ConfigurationManager` class to save there also the configs. For code examples you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274829/configurationmanager-appsettings-how-to-modify-and-save)

Comment: Modify the legacy application to use [Microsoft.Extension.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/) as well. The package targets .NET Standard 2.0 and and Framework 4.6.2 among others. .NET Framework 4.6.1 is out of support, 4.6.2 is the oldest supported .NET Framework version, found in all supported Windows versions. Chances are your application is already running on a 4.6.2 runtime because you can't downgrade runtimes

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to modify the .NET Framework code to use [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/). The package targets .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.2 among others. So does [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting). One could easily add a generic host with preconfigured DI, Configuration, logging etc and read connection strings with :

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args).Build();
var configuration=host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

var connectionString=configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB");
```

or, if we're very, very lazy :

```
var builder=Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
var connectionString=builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB");
```

or use just the Configuration middleware:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();
```

The .NET Framework configuration system makes it hard to even use custom XML sections, much less JSON files. Even adding a custom XML section requires creating a new assembly that's referenced in `app.config`.

By the way, 4.6.1 [went out of support 2 years ago](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/). By that time, all supported Windows versions already run 4.6.2 at least. Right now the oldest supported runtime is 4.6.2.