# How to make Windows System Restore ignore some of my application files?

Tags: trial, software-protection, system-restore

I am experimenting with software copy protection ideas and now I have the following problem.

I have a trial version of my application. Trial data are stored in a certain file and also in some certain registry keys. Of course I know that user can break this trial protection by using some registry and file monitoring and backup tools but I want at least protect against some simple hacks like date-time changes and using Windows System Restore.

The problem is that Windows System Restore wipes out all my application files and also the trial data. I know that System Restore does not affect User's documents folder but I not want to store the trial datafile there, because it is too obvious.

Is there any way I can stop System Restore to remove my trial data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store it in the <strike>user's doc</strike> application folder?

- Encrypt the content in the file
- When the file is gone, trial is over

Application folder

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425869.aspx

Security through obscurity

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Other option is the use of the application settings

[Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-application)

Comment: That would be too obvious: user will look in the docs folder and see that there is some weird file.

Comment: Why is it relevant that the user notices strange files?

Comment: Because users sometimes delete strange files in their data folders, especially because there are lots of viruses as .exe, .inf, .jpg.exe, fake recycle bin files. I know many people, who delete from their flash memory sticks everything that they did not write there themselves, and some people do the same for their documents folder.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but since the selected answer doesn't answer the question asked I figured I'd add my answer for anyone else that ends up here.

To make System Restore ignore files add a REG_MULTI_SZ registry value to the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToBackup
```

Environment variable and wild can be used. To include subdirectories add " /s" to the end. For example to add everything in c:\temp using reg.exe from the command line

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToBackup /v Temp /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "c:\temp\* /s"
```