# WPF MRU List Inline

Tags: wpf, mru

I am creating an MRU, Most Recent Used, class for my WPF application.  I have the main class working and it manages the list of recent files.

My issue is displaying the list of files inline.  All of the examples that I can find display the list in a submenu, where you can the MRU helper class the sub menu item and it can add, remove and clear the list of recent files.  I want to have this list on my main File menu.  I know I once saw an example, which I can no longer find, that had you derive your MRU class from Separator.  You included this class on your File menu.  If no recent files exist it would just display a separator.  If you had a list it would display the separator, the list of files and another separator.

I don't want my MRU helper class to have any knowledge or reference to my File menu.  I want to be able to somehow have a placeholder in my File menu that my MRU helper class will have knowledge of and be able to create whatever items it needs.

I was also planning on storing my MRU list in Properties.Settings.Default rather than the registry.  I notice most examples use the registry.  Am I wrong to do it this way?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23731/RecentFileList-a-WPF-MRU).

There is nothing wrong with storing the list in `Properties.Settings`. You can create a `StringCollection` entry for the list. IMO it is better than registry which you don't know whether the user has access. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/453173/986080).