# saving details within application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a C# windows forms application. When I launch the project, a dialog box will appear with menus. In a particular menu, I choose Options and Options dialog box opens. Inside that, I need to enter a username and password and validate it against the DB. If credentials are correct, I should make a login form to display (I have login form as part of my project), upon closing the project and running it the next time. How do I go about doing this?

How and where should I store the result of the validation of username and password and make the project remember to launch the login form, when I launch the project next time???

Comment: Note that whatever method you choose, I recommend you don't store passwords in plain-text.  In fact, coming up with your own mechanism for storing passwords at all (without a lot of "best practice" design input) is generally dangerous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Project Properties > Settings option. VS will generate class for the settings and you can access them via **Properties.Settings.Default.[PropertyName]**

```
if(chkRememberMe.Checked)
{
Properties.Settings.Default.Username = txtUsername.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Password = txtPassword.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

And while loading back

```
txtUsername.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Username;
txtPassword.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the app config file to save local application data
[How to: Add Application Configuration Files to C# Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) 
and this is usefull
[How to use appconfig](http://generally.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/using-appconfig-for-user-defined-runtime-parameters/)

Answer (score 0):

You should save the information into a file in any of the following directories:

- `ApplicationData`
- `LocalApplicationData`

See [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).