# Cannot reuse wpf window after closing

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a window to change database configuration for my application. Settings button click is handeled by Config(), it show settings windows when clicked. If I close the using cross sign on the right corner of window, I am not able to reuse the windows it shows following exception.

Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.

```
ConfigDialogBox configDlg = new ConfigDialogBox();

        private void SettingsChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Database.host = configDlg.host;
            Database.port = configDlg.port;
            Database.user = configDlg.user;
            Database.password = configDlg.password;
            Database.database = configDlg.database;            
            ConfigDlg.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private void Config(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            configDlg.Show();
            configDlg.okButton.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(SettingsChanged);
            configDlg.cancelButton.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(SettingsChanged);
        }

        void cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
           ConfigDlg.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```

How can I reuse it after closing?

Comment: Why do you need to re-use it, couldn't you just create a new one?

Comment: This windows contains database configuration and I will lose all settings if the windows is closed. It is working fine with ok and cancel, only close causing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reuse the window.

If closing the window via something other than <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons is your problem, you need to handle the [`Window.Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) event (see the link for an example).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Just create a new window.

Comment: Actually all settings will be lost if window is closed that is not desired.

Comment: I think the change you are suggesting is adding                       configDlg = new ConfigDialogBox();  before configDlg.show, it is not solving my problem.

Comment: Don't store settings in the `ConfigDialogBox` instance. Save it elsewhere, when closing dialog with 'OK' button.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfigDialogBox configDlg = null;



private void Config(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
         configDlg = new ConfigDialogBox();
            configDlg.Show();
            configDlg.okButton.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(SettingsChanged);
            configDlg.cancelButton.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(SettingsChanged);
        }
```

Comment: or u can cancel the onclosing event with e.Cancel = true;

Comment: also look here, cause u would need a persistent way of storing yr settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-application