# Analog of IsolatedStorageSettings in full (desktop) .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there any analog to IsolatedStorageSettings (WP7, Silverlight) in Desktop .Net 3.5?

PS: I nead this king of functionality to work everywere. Do i have to implement this file from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at following option: [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-application)

If you need to port application, it might be easier to decouple loading/saving settings via IoC then just implement interface using options in the question above.