# Embed serialized data into executable

Tags: c#, embed, executable, single-file

I'm currently working on a small project where I have a list of lists of objects, which I need to store between program executions. The scale of the project is in my opinion not large enough to start developing an external DB-solution, so I would like to store the data inside the executable, so the end-user does not have to keep track of multiple files. Is this possible at all? I've been thinking about embedding the file as a resource, but as I have read, it is not possible to edit this resource file without recompiling the project, so this is not a solution. Alternatively I have read about Alternate Data Streams, but I don't know if it is a good idea to edit the executable this way?

So all in all I need the executable to store data between executions, without the need for managing other files.

I hope you are able to help me.

Comment: Editing the exe is not a good dea; most users shouldnt have write access to programs, and it breaks signing etc. a secondary file, automatically loaded by the app from the user's profile area is preferred. App-settings would do this nicely.

Comment: App-settings unfortunately doesn't solve the problem, since i want the program to be as portable as possible. Eg. a user copies the executable to a portable media and inserts this media in another computer. If all the data is stored in app-settings, the data is lost. I need the data to follow the executable no matter where and how you access it. My current solution is XML-serialization of all objects, but that generates the problem with an executable and a data file to keep track of, which i want to avoid. Don't know if it is at all possible?

Comment: not unless you use cloud storage or similar. Don't edit your own exe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are the way to go here.

More explained at [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-application)