# Saving the form state then opening it back up in the same state

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, savestate

I have a small program in `winforms` that holds 3 buttons. Thus far the program lets the user change a the color of another button by clicking the corresponding button While the third button does not do anything yet. What I want to do is to let the user save changes made to the form (save the form state). So when the form is reopened it opens in that same state as saved.

I hope I am being clear about what I am after

Here is a visualization of the form:

[image]

The code that i have so far if any help:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnToColor.Text = "";
        }

        int c = 0;
        private void btnColorSwap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (c == 0)
            {
                btnToColor.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                c++;

            }

            else if (c == 1)
            {
                btnToColor.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;

                c++;
            }

            else if (c == 2)
            {
                btnToColor.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;

                c = 0;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to save state just in that process, or between app executions?

Comment: I'm not sure what any of this means to be honest I'm looking for a simple way to save the state of the form

Comment: I mean, do you want to save the state so that next time you run the program the form goes back to that state, or so that next time you open the form after just closing the form (without ending the program)?

Comment: I want to save the state so that next time I run the program the form goes back to that state

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may/may not be easier for you.

Start by creating a class to hold your state:

```
public class MyFormState {
    public string ButtonBackColor { get; set; }
}
```

Now, declare a member for your `Form` with this object:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    MyFormState state = new MyFormState();
```

On form load, check if the config exists, then load it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (File.Exists("config.xml")) {
        loadConfig();
    }

    button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(state.ButtonBackColor);
}

private void loadConfig() {
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyFormState));
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("config.xml")) {
        state = (MyFormState)ser.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}
```

When your form is closing.. save the config:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    writeConfig();
}

private void writeConfig() {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("config.xml")) {
        state.ButtonBackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(button1.BackColor);
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyFormState));
        ser.Serialize(sw, state);
    }
}
```

Then you can add members to your state class and they will be written into the config.xml file.

Comment: The solution works good. The problem is that in case you would need to do this for all items in a listbox, things get icky really fast if you iterate with a foreach loop through the items in the listbox and serialize each item(which you HAVE to do). On load you get a nice exception saying that you've already declared the XML namespace one at the beginning of the file and you're doing it each time you serialize. Any workaround that ?

Comment: Simply store them in a list of strings. The serializer will take care of it.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a look in the project property pages you can add a settings file.

To use the settings in code you would do something like:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName
```

Do bare in mind though that these settings are local and would need to be specified on each machine

Sample Code :

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.btn1 = button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor ? Color.Transparent : button1.BackColor;
        Properties.Settings.Default.btn2 = button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor ? Color.Transparent : button2.BackColor;
        Properties.Settings.Default.btn3 = button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor ? Color.Transparent : button3.BackColor;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.btn1 != Color.Transparent) button1.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.btn1;
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.btn2 != Color.Transparent) button1.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.btn2;
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.btn3 != Color.Transparent) button1.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.btn3;
    }
```

Here is a link to the settings class on MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx

---

### PropertyPages

[image: Property Setting Page]

Comment: And for each user.  Unless he is using application settings which are more difficult to change.

Comment: I have a silly question what are project property pages? And where can I find them?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to serialize the form? .. I mean in terms of future development.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - i think he just wants to save the Button Colors not the whole data!

Comment: @Tacit - check the image at end of answer!

Comment: @AppDeveloper thanks you I am going through it and hopefully I will get it working

Comment: @AppDeveloper I cant seem to get it working i tried the code added the settings but doesn't save not sure what I'm doing wrong p.s why does the value have to be black?

Comment: @Tacit - that happened in hurry, pls make it Color.Transparent!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23740/discussion-between-appdeveloper-and-tacit)

Answer (score 0):

usually when it come to store an user interface setting the standard way is to use XML file to save or load the setting i made this example that save user interface components using xml hope it be useful

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1j1qbe7udqxizr6/4.XMLConfigurationEditor.rar?dl=0