# Writing form state to xml C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

My aim is to save the all form data via button click (as opposed to upon closing). To that end, I've used the example given in the following thread. [Saving the form state then opening it back up in the same state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616958/saving-the-form-state-then-opening-it-back-up-in-the-same-state)

I've tried to adapt my code to the best of my ability, but nothing happens, and there are no errors shown. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmPayroll : Form
    {
        SaveData sd = new SaveData();
        public frmPayroll()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            writeConfig();
        }
        private void writeConfig()
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("config.xml"))
            {
                sd.Married = rdoMarr.Checked;
                sd.PayPd = cbPayPd.Text;
                sd.Allow = cbAllow.Text;
                sd.Gross = txtGross.Text;
                sd.Fit = txtFit.Text;
                sd.Soc = txtSoc.Text;
                sd.Med = txtMed.Text;
                sd.NetPay = txtNet.Text;
                sd.PayPd = cbPayPd.Text;
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveData));
                ser.Serialize(sw, sd);
            }
        }
        private void frmPayroll_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists("config.xml"))
            {
                loadConfig();
            }
            sd.Married = rdoMarr.Checked;
            sd.PayPd = cbPayPd.Text;
            sd.Allow = cbAllow.Text;
            sd.Gross = txtGross.Text;
            sd.Fit = txtFit.Text;
            sd.Soc = txtSoc.Text;
            sd.Med = txtMed.Text;
            sd.NetPay = txtNet.Text;
        }
        private void loadConfig()
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveData));
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("config.xml"))
            {
                sd = (SaveData)ser.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }
    }
    public struct SaveData
    {
        public bool Married;
        public string PayPd;
        public string Allow;
        public string Gross;
        public string Fit;
        public string Soc;
        public string Med;
        public string NetPay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading your object by deserializing.

But Where are you assigning the states back to your controls?

look at `frmPayroll_Load` function.

You are trying to assign the data back to the object again.

**You have to assign data back to form controls.**

Should be something like this (you may need to apply data conversions if required):

```
rdoMarr.Checked = sd.Married;
.
.
.
.
txtFit.Text = sd.Fit;
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: THANKS!! It worked as soon as I tried that. I was racking my brain trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. I'm taking a c# class, but haven't taken any of the prerequisite, so its sometimes a little difficult to understand what many of the tutorials or examples on MSDN are saying. Now to attempt to add a clear button.

Comment: I tried to up-vote your answer, but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: Sorry about that, and thanks for the help. I'm new here, but the deed is now done