# How to add desktop path to app.config file?

Tags: c#, app-config

I am creating an C# win form application where user can specify any location to save a file. But, in default I need to provide the desktop path. But the desktop path changes depend on the Windows version, I found that:
 `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);` 
can get the desktop path of any windows version. But the problem is how do I add this code to `App.config` file? Is there are special xml code block for this.

Comment: You might want to use the [Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) file instead

Comment: I would suggest reading this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application). should answer you question as well

Comment: I used the settings file. The link @MrGTgo gave me was the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a settings-file to your project. There you need to create a property in the application-scope.  This property you can access by

```
string path = Properties.Settings.Default.Path;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
{
   path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
}
```

Comment: I just did that. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go through [AppDomain.GetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getdata.aspx) and [AppDomain.SetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c.aspx) 
Have a constant like DESKTOP_DIRECTORY in you application & set its value to `SpecialFolders.Desktop`

You can then use `AppDomain.GetData` to retrieve it back.

You can then use it in your `App.config` file.