# Project wide string variable

Tags: c#

Essentially on form load I want a basic VB input box to prompt the user for input in the form of a string (a servername, like MYSERVER01). As of now I am accomplishing like:

```
        //Get server name from user
        string serverName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter the name of the server hosting the share (without '\\\\')", "File copy from Server", "", -1, -1);
        string remotePath = @"\\" + serverName + @"\" + "Share";
```

However, I need `remotePath` to be available throughout the the entire project, my question is, where I define it, bearing in mind I only want the messagebox to prompt the user once for the servername.

Comment: You want a static property.

Comment: You want a different way to solve this. Either change the working directory and access files by relative path, or use a class that abstracts that, which can use the path in an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way;

```
public static class SomeClass
{
    //Get server name from user
    string serverName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter the name of the server hosting the share (without '\\\\')", "File copy from Server", "", -1, -1);
    private static string remotePath = @"\\" + serverName + @"\" + "Share";

    public static string RemotePath
    {
        get
        {
            return remotePath;
        }

        set
        {
            remotePath = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can access `remotePath` throughout the application.To access **remotePath** from other classes use `SomeClass.RemotePath`,it's a get and set property so you can change it later on if you need.

Comment: Why not make this a static class and drop the constructor?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the suggestion.Is it fine now ?

Comment: Yea, but where is `serverName` coming from?

Comment: A static class that _pops up an inputbox_ when it is first accessed? Don't do this, even if it would compile.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are talking about program settings. The standard place to store them is .settings file. Storing settings is as easy as

```
Settings.Default["ServerName"] = "MYSERVER01";
```

Take a look at this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/453230/731793.
Also read the official documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx