# IsolatedStorageSettings missing assembly

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I'm trying to save some settings related data on my Windows Forms application using IsolatedStorageSettings. But as soon as I create an instance of that class, I have an error saying that IsolatedStorageSettings does not exists on the namespace. This is my code :

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

namespace HangedGame
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string word;
    string foundWord;
    int count;
    private System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings =
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
}
}
```

What is wrong whit it?

Comment: in winform applications you cannot use isolatedstorage, isolated stroage can be use in windows phone or windows metro style applications. You can easily store your data in memory in a winform app, or xml or any sql server

Comment: @AOZ I come actually from a Mac development background so I'm not that familiar with c# or winforms. What would be the equivalent of NSUserSettings in c#?

Comment: NSUserSettings ~= IsolatedStorage :) in windows phone and metro style apps. But i guess you have to use a xml or database to keep users data. You should search using db (ado.net) or entity framework. It is very simple to use a db in .Net

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/453230/2387977

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`Creating a Folder and File under IsolatedStorage`

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore((IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User), null, null))
{
    storage.CreateDirectory(@"SampleStorageFolder");
    storage.CreateFile(@"SampleStorageFolder\ReadMe.txt");
}
```

`Reading File created under IsolatedStorage`

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore((IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User), null, null))
{
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(storage.OpenFile("ReadMe.txt", FileMode.Open)))
    {
       string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```