# Changes with SetEnvrionmentVariable cant be read with GetEvironmentVaribale until reboot?

Tags: c#, environment-variables

New to Envriroment Variable usage.

I am coding project setup tool and need to store some user specified project directory paths across sessions.
Someone suggested Get/SetEvironmentVariable. 
So I set up a Windows Form with textBoxes to display the paths.
When I load the form it uses GetEvironmentVariable, and the textBoxes populate as expected.
but when I try to update values with SetEvironmentVariable , 
the textBoxes are empty and do not show the updated variable until rebooting.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("my_project_dir", "C:\path\to\my\project" , EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine );
        textBox1.Text = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_project_dir", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
    }
```

Comment: On Advice of a more experienced Tools coder I opted for Apllication Settings rather than Environment Variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are setting the environment variable to be a machine-wide variable. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

> The environment variable is stored or retrieved from the
>   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\Environment** key in the Windows operating system registry. 
>   When a user creates the environment variable in a set operation, the
>   operating system stores the environment variable in the system
>   registry, but not in the current process. If any user on the local
>   machine starts a new process, the operating system copies the
>   environment variable from the registry to that process.
>
> When the process terminates, the operating system destroys the
>   environment variable in that process. However, the environment
>   variable in the registry persists until a user removes it
>   programmatically or
>   by means of an operating system tool.

The important part is this:

> When a user creates the environment variable in a set operation, the
>   operating system stores the environment variable in the system
>   registry, but not in the current process.

What you want to do instead is use `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process` (which is the default, so you don't need to specify anything), which will store the environment variable in the environment block associated with the current process.