# C# Application Settings in Visual Studio Per Company

Tags: c#, application-settings

We have a web application that manages assets for our company. Each asset belongs to a company.
We have some hard-coded logic that sets rules based on the company the asset is related to.
I would like to rework this inline code and use a settings based approach.
I am not sure what the best implementation would be. There is an application settings file that allows you to store application or user specific data, can I use this?
Basically, we will have a group of settings with values for each company.
For example:
we might have a setting called: CanUploadDocuments. This value will be either true or false depending on the company the asset is related to.
What would be the best and most efficient way to build/store these company based settings in a C# 4.0 web application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Comment: I agree with @KenWhite that this is a duplicate. The fact that it is a web application vs a windows form application doesn't change the question or the answer.