# Read and write the same file c#

Tags: c#, io

I want to make a simple game, with a login interface first, when you create your account I want the username, password and level to be stored in login.txt file. Later, when you login, it verifies your level from the file and opens a specific form.

I tried to use

```
StreamReader sR = new StreamReader("login.txt");
StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter("login.txt");
```

It doesn't work.

How can I do it in a simple way?

Comment: Take a look at `FileShare.ReadWrite` field in `FileShare` enum.

Comment: are you closing sR , sW after each use??

Comment: Use project settings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/453230/351383 , better than reinventing the wheel ;)

Comment: Are you sure using System.IO is added ?!

Comment: i dont get errors with my code, the single error is that streamReader and streamWriter can't use the same file

Comment: can someone explain me, or give me and example with fileShare.ReadWrite?

Comment: For reasonably large text files, I'd use [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143376.aspx) and [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143369.aspx).

Comment: Id rather use a small database either way. May guess is that you won't only need this text file but many like it. So rather use something else. Also saving a file on the disk is not the best way to keep login credentials save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"login.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
...
}
```

FileAccess.ReadWrite allows you to both read and write on the stream and FileShare.ReadWrite allows you to have more than one reader OR writer to the file

So in theory you can have two of these if you wish

PS: I would not use a textfile to do the login credentials of anything.

Comment: thank you very much, considering your comment i decided to use a local database to store my intel. Again thanks