# Application.settings file property change doesn't reflect in Visual Studio's GUI value text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, application-settings

I am using c#.net console project, Visual Studio 2013 with .Net Version 4.5. My need is to persist information which would change dynamically and would need to exist across application sessions. I am able to accomplish this using the `Application.Settings` file.

I created the settings file and the key with `value="oldValue"` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application). Now I am able to edit and save using below code.

```
Settings.Default["key"] = "newValue";
Settings.Default.Save();
```

This value is persisted and the change reflects across application sessions. However, when I open the `Application.Settings` file through visual studio, in the GUI value text box the value is still the `"oldValue"`. Why doesn't it change?

Comment: because it is the default initial value.  the runtime settings will have been saved to file

Comment: Is it possible to view the present value stored in the variable? Other than accessing the value through code.

Comment: you could open the file

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i resolved it:

In VS2013 go to Solution Explorer and under your Solution find your project and right click on the project then select properties then go to Settings click on it, you see that your old values still there, But you need to CLICK on Value Field then a (... button) on the right of the field will APPEAR click on this button for your new value to be updated.

That is it!