# Change background image of form as soon as button on another form is clicked

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I am having two forms (`A` and `B`). In form `B` there are many buttons having different background image. On clicking any of the button I want to change the background image of form `A` to the background image of the button which was clicked instantly as it is always open behind the form.

```
formA mai = new formA();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mai.BackgroundImage = button1.BackgroundImage;
    }
```

This is the code I am using although it changes the background image it doesn't change instantly but if I will open and close the form the background image will be changed.
I don't need like that I need it to change instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field in `formB` to refer to the `formA` instance which you want to change its `BackgroundImage`; and initialize it when you call `formB`

`formB`'s code-behind:

```
public partial class formB : Form
{
    public formA owner;

    public formB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (owner != null)
            owner.BackgroundImage = button1.BackgroundImage;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (owner != null)
            owner.BackgroundImage = button2.BackgroundImage;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (owner != null)
            owner.BackgroundImage = button3.BackgroundImage;
    }
}
```

`formA`'s code-behind:

```
public partial class formA : Form
{
    public formA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formB b = new formB();
        b.owner = this;
        b.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you also tell me how to save the change of image

Comment: Take a look at this.. [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 0):

Add `this.Refresh()`

```
formA mai = new formA();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mai.BackgroundImage = button1.BackgroundImage;
    mai.BringToFront();
    mai.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `mai.Invalidate()` after setting the new image.

Comment: not working should i have to write something in FormA