# How to simulate the file attribute of a .config file's appSettings section

Tags: c#, app-config

Microsoft gives [instructions for how to use the `file` attribute](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555396) to make a `.config` file's `appSettings` section reference another file: For example:

```
<appSettings file="c:\commonSettings.config">
    <add key="myAppSpecificSetting" value="Setting1" />
</appSettings>
```

However, this is [implemented specifically for only `appSettings`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/AppSettingsSection.cs,57601081a37c379f) and isn't some general `.config` file feature.

Now, I have implemented my own `ConfigurationSection`, and would like to be able to specify `file=` just like one can with `appSettings`. Aside from simply creating the property to match the attribute and retrieve the file name, how can I actually recreate/simulate this functionality in my custom `configSection`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully we have [the source code now](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/AppSettingsSection.cs,8b5ec3fad37125b4). It looks like it's just something implemented by `AppSettingsSection` by reading the file system, nothing special you can reuse in your own configuration section.

```
protected internal override void DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, bool serializeCollectionKey) 
{
    string ElementName = reader.Name;

    base.DeserializeElement(reader, serializeCollectionKey);
    if ((File != null) && (File.Length > 0)) {
        string sourceFileFullPath;
        string configFileDirectory;
        string configFile;

        // Determine file location
        configFile = ElementInformation.Source;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(configFile)) {
            sourceFileFullPath = File;
        }
        else {
            configFileDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(configFile);
            sourceFileFullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(configFileDirectory, File);
        }

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(sourceFileFullPath)) {
            int lineOffset = 0;
            string rawXml = null;

            using (Stream sourceFileStream = new FileStream(sourceFileFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
                using (XmlUtil xmlUtil = new XmlUtil(sourceFileStream, sourceFileFullPath, true)) {
                    if (xmlUtil.Reader.Name != ElementName) {
                        throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(
                                SR.GetString(SR.Config_name_value_file_section_file_invalid_root, ElementName),
                                xmlUtil);
                    }

                    lineOffset = xmlUtil.Reader.LineNumber;
                    rawXml = xmlUtil.CopySection();

                    // Detect if there is any XML left over after the section
                    while (!xmlUtil.Reader.EOF) {
                        XmlNodeType t = xmlUtil.Reader.NodeType;
                        if (t != XmlNodeType.Comment) {
                            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(SR.GetString(SR.Config_source_file_format), xmlUtil);
                        }

                        xmlUtil.Reader.Read();
                    }
                }
            }

            ConfigXmlReader internalReader = new ConfigXmlReader(rawXml, sourceFileFullPath, lineOffset);
            internalReader.Read();
            if (internalReader.MoveToNextAttribute()) {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(SR.GetString(SR.Config_base_unrecognized_attribute, internalReader.Name), (XmlReader)internalReader);
            }

            internalReader.MoveToElement();

            base.DeserializeElement(internalReader, serializeCollectionKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that method (see the link to the source code in my question) but didn't know it was involved (I see the `File` property reference now, though). When does DeserializeElement get called?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but I assume somewhere in the bowels of ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Note to self: always look at the `override` methods in a class you're trying to understand, because they can connect custom functionality to base class functionality...

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't really help. I can't duplicate the functionality because I can't override the `DeserializeElement` method in my own class... back to the drawing board.