# Edit values in appconfig.json using C#

Tags: c#, json

Is there any way to edit value inside appsetting.json using controller?

So, here is the appsetting.json:

```
{
    "Person": {
    "p1": "test1",
    "p2": "test2",
    "p3": "test3"
    }
}
```

and this is the class:

```
public class
{
    public string p1{ get; set; }

    public string p2{ get; set; }

    public string p3{ get; set; }
}
```

I do some research but no clue. I just find how to read the value of  appsetting.json. What I want is to edit the value from controller and save it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core appsettings.json update in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653688/asp-net-core-appsettings-json-update-in-code)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); 
            config.AppSettings.Settings["p1"].Value = "test1";       
            config.AppSettings.Settings["p2"].Value = "test2";  
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```