# How to load dynamic dbcontext based on database name obtained from another dbcontext?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing a Web API application with ASP.NET Core 5 with the goal of being multitenant capable. Each tenant will have their own database.

In this application I will have two `DbContext`:

- `DBContextMaster` - this context data will be static in `appsettings.json`. It will get the information of the tenant making the request from the Web API and get the name of the database stored for that specific customer
- `DBContextTenant` - this context will have a connection string in `appsettings` similar to this:

  ```
    "DynamicTenant": "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog={dbName};Integrated Security=False.
  ```

  `{dbName}` must be replaced in order for the correct database to be used.

I have some questions about how to do this, but my idea would be:

- send the tenant code or a kind of APIKEY with the request
- validate if the tenant exists and then replace the `DynamicTenant` connection string (deploy some kind of cache to avoid successive queries checking if the same tenant exists)

As I am just starting with ASP.NET Core, I would like to know how and where I could dynamically load the tenant context.

UPDATE:

This code will apparently serve me well.

```
   services.AddDbContext<DbContextTenant>((serviceProvider, dbContextBuilder) =>
        {
            var connectionStringPlaceHolder = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DynamicTenant");
            var httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var dbName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["tenantId"].First();
            var connectionString = connectionStringPlaceHolder.Replace("{dbName}", dbName);
            dbContextBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        });
```

But now I have another problem. When running the project there is no error, but when trying to add a new controller using this dbcontext, the following error occurs "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Same error when I try to enable Migrations for the project.

I assume the error is occurring because at development time there is no http context.

What implementation can be done to get around these problems?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68822517/multiple-dbcontext-at-run-time-with-multiple-providers/68823734#68823734

Answer (score 2):

`send the tenant code or a kind of APIKEY with the request`

You are doing right.

there are ways of getting tenants from users, you can use headers, you can use a query string, you can use a host (for example IP address or domain name) or a parameter to all your actions for example an API key.

but I suggest you, use host or header, so you can add a middleware for that to monitor all requests.

Look at this example:

```
public class TenantMiddleware
{

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TenantMiddleware (RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public TenantMiddleware (RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }


    public async Task Invoke (HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(_tenantKey, out StringValues host);
        var tenantHolder = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITenantHolder>();
        tenantHolder.SetTenant(_tenantKey);
    }

}
```

`tenantHolder` is a scoped service that has the `tenantId` for each request and you can get the data from that. it just has a variable that gives you the tenant, you can also use it as a factory for your contexts.

you can find more details on this repo:
[TenantProvider](https://github.com/mrtarkhan/Sayda.Core.TenantProvider)

Comment: I would not want to use external library, as apparently this is an issue with a simpler solution

Comment: @Marcoscdoni it is not an external library, I had your issue before and I solved it by myself. that repo is written by me. it is not a library. it is a GitHub repo. you can check the sources, I did it by strategy pattern and it supports two ways of getting tenant

Answer (score 0):

Send tenant code in each request is correct.

If you use only one connection string for request and you pass the neme on Header you can do this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ContextDb>(options =>
            {
                var context = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
                // get key from HttpContext and create your connectionString

                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            },
            ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```