# how to save settings in c# .net core 3.1 console application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, settings

As usual, I added a Settings file to my application:
[image]

For now the file contains one datetime property which I assign after the application code ran through:
[image]

As usual, I assign the property as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Properties.Default.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

**Issue**
Normally, I would then save the settings to file as follows but for some reason, VS does not like it:
[image]
[image]

full code as requested:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Properties.Default.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    Properties.Default.Save();
    Properties.Default.Reload();
}
```

Comment: That error usually means you're not calling the correct instance. This is usually `Properties.Settings.Default`, but without seeing the code (instead of pictures of user interface elements), it hard to say.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield added the full program code (although its not much)

Comment: You need to post the designer code that defines the settings class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the new configuration options provided by .net core.

-> Add appsettings.json to your project

**appsettings.json**

```
{
"name" : "Gary"
}
```

**Init**

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
      .Build();
```

In this discussion you will also find a way how to update the value at runtime:

[ASP.NET Core appsettings.json update in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653688/asp-net-core-appsettings-json-update-in-code)