# want to put the model in "builder.Services.Configure"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

When configuring the builder in "ASP.NET Core", I want to put the data model I created myself.
It is intended to be delivered to middleware or "Add Scoped" services.

I've tried the following code:

```
TestUtilsSettingModel temp = new TestUtilsSettingModel()
{
    Test01 = 1000,
    Test03 = "Input!!"
};


//error
builder.Services
    .Configure<TestUtilsSettingModel>(temp);

//error
builder.Services
    .Configure<TestUtilsSettingModel>(
        new Action<TestUtilsSettingModel>(temp));

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/45324839/6725889
builder.Configuration["TestUtilsSetting:Test01"] = 1000.ToString();
```

[Test Code and project here.](https://github.com/dang-gun/DotNetTest/tree/main/MiddlewareOptionsTest)

"Configuration["TestUtilsSetting:Test01"]" works but
You have to put all the data yourself.


Can't you just pass the whole data model?




Here is the test code:

class to receive options:

[Code here.](https://github.com/dang-gun/DotNetTest/blob/main/MiddlewareOptionsTest/TestUtils.cs)

```
public interface ITestUtils
{
}

public class TestUtils: ITestUtils
{
    private readonly TestUtilsSettingModel _appSettings;

    public TestUtils(IOptions<TestUtilsSettingModel> appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

}
```

Inject from "Program.cs" or "Startup.cs"

[Code here.](https://github.com/dang-gun/DotNetTest/blob/main/MiddlewareOptionsTest/Program.cs)

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITestUtils, TestUtils>();
```

Used in controller constructor :

[Code here.](https://github.com/dang-gun/DotNetTest/blob/main/MiddlewareOptionsTest/Controllers/WeatherForecastController.cs)

```
    public WeatherForecastController(
        ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger
        , ITestUtils testMiddleware)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        this._TestMiddleware = testMiddleware;
    }
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: How will you use this model in rest of the code?

Comment: What if you do just `builder.Services
    .Configure<TestUtilsSettingModel>();`?

Comment: @Chetan Could not convert from 'MiddlewareOptionsTest.TestUtilsSettingModel' to 'System.Action<MiddlewareOptionsTest.TestUtilsSettingModel>'.

Comment: Error CS1501 No overload for method 'Configure' with 0 arguments.

Comment: Are you planning to inject this model class object in to other classes in the application? How are you planning to access this model class object after you configure in the builder.Services?

Comment: Added the code of the test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I studied 'iservicecollection extension' to solve this problem.
I found a solution.

The following code is equivalent to 
'builder.Configuration["TestUtilsSetting:Test01"] = 1000.ToString();'

```
builder.Services.Configure<TestUtilsSettingModel>(options =>
{
    options.Test01 = 1000;
});
```

You still have to put each one in.
('options = temp' not work)



So do something like this:

Add the following method to 'TestUtilsSettingModel'.

```
public void ToCopy(TestUtilsSettingModel testUtilsSettingModel)
{
    this.Test01 = testUtilsSettingModel.Test01;
    this.Test02 = testUtilsSettingModel.Test02;
    this.Test03 = testUtilsSettingModel.Test03;
}
```

In 'Program.cs', pass the model as follows.

```
builder.Services.Configure<TestUtilsSettingModel>(options =>
{
    options.ToCopy(temp);
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiGux.png)