# Update appsetting.json in run time in .netcore

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, appsettings

I have this appsetting json file :

```
"RavenOptions": {
    "PublicUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:61570",
    "PublicDbName": "TestHostBuilder_ctor_1",
    "TseDbName": "TestHostBuilder_ctor_1",
    "IsHttps": "false",
    "CertificateDirectory": "",
    "ShardUrls": [
      "http://127.0.0.1:61570",
      "http://127.0.0.1:61570",
      "http://127.0.0.1:61570",
      "http://127.0.0.1:61570"
    ]
  }
```

I need to update the values of the file in runtime .I am using this function :

```
 public static void AddOrUpdateAppSetting<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        try
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "appSettingTest.json");
            string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            var sectionPath = key.Split(":")[0];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sectionPath))
            {
                var keyPath = key.Split(":")[1];
                jsonObj[sectionPath][keyPath] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                jsonObj[sectionPath] = value; // if no sectionpath just set the value
            }

            string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error writing app settings");
        }
    }
```

this function works fine but the problem is when I want to update the values of `sharedurls` (this is an array) the result is like this :

[image]

All records are in one row .But I need tho be like this :

[image]

every records is one row.
Here is my update code :

```
string serverAddress = "\""+documentStore.Identifier.Split("(").First()+"\"";
        Appset.AddOrUpdateAppSetting("RavenOptions:PublicDbName", documentStore.Database);
        Appset.AddOrUpdateAppSetting("RavenOptions:PublicUrl", documentStore.Identifier.Split("(").First());
        Appset.AddOrUpdateAppSetting("RavenOptions:ShardUrls","["+String.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat(serverAddress, 4).ToArray())+"]");
```

Comment: First, why are you doing this instead of using a better config source like eg a database? `appsettings.json` is nothing special, it's just a default JSON file name. Second, ASP.NET Core uses System.Text.Json. Why add yet another dependency to JSON.NET ? Or go through `dynamic`? Both with JSON.NET and STJ you can parse the entire document, modify a node and save it back. With STJ you can use [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parse?view=net-6.0). There's no reason to split names and values, that's done by the JSON serializer

Comment: As for `all records are in one row` it doesn't matter **at all** as long as the values are in an array. One row or many, when any JSON setting file (which doesn't have to be appsettings.json` is loaded, the array index value will be appended to the section/value path.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your response ,In fact I am using ravenTestDriver for my unittests,RavenTestDriver is a fake inmemory databae for ravendb .when I run my test the diver sets a random port for the database,so I have to inject this port to my application using jsonfile .I hope that I could explain the problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos here in my test I should inject Ioption<RavenOptions> to main application :           services.Configure<IOptions<domain.Environments.RavenOptions>>(options => Configuration.GetSection("RavenOptions").Bind(options));

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as you can see Configuration.GetSection("RavenOptions").Bind(options) returns the values from raventestdriver that I set before and inject it ti my application ,any solution I will be appreciated

Comment: This doesn't explain why you used such code at all. The problem isn't RavenDB. It looks like you [copied these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653688/asp-net-core-appsettings-json-update-in-code) which don't work for arrays. You can't "emulate" a JSON array value, you must store an actual JSON array object. A `T[]` instead of a `T` and *definitely* not a string

Comment: To resume, you want edit a json file. Maybe this can help you : [Modifying JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos             string[] shardurl=new string[] { serverAddress,serverAddress,serverAddress,serverAddress};
            Appset.AddOrUpdateAppSetting("RavenOptions:ShardUrls", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shardurl));
 is it true?