# Read appsettings.json in Main Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

First of all my main purpose is to setup the IP and Port for my application dynamically.

I'm using `IConfiguration` to inject a json config file, like some tutorial mentioned.

However, I can't retrieve the configuration in Program.cs, because my `WebHostBuilder` will use the StartUp and Url at the same time.

So at the time the host build up, there is nothing in my configuration.

```
WebProtocolSettings settings_Web = new WebProtocolSettings();
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls(settings_Web.Url + ":" + settings_Web.Port)
                .Build();
```

In Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Set up configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adds services required for using options.
    services.AddOptions();

    var _WebProtocolSettings = Configuration.GetSection("WebProtocolSettings");

    // Register the IConfiguration instance
    services.Configure<WebProtocolSettings>(_WebProtocolSettings);
}
```

My appsettings.json:

```
{
    "WebProtocolSettings": {
        "Url": "127.0.0.1",
        "Port": 5050
    }
}
```

My WebProtocolSettings.cs:

```
public class WebProtocolSettings
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Update .Net 6

It's now easy to get any settings from the [ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) by calling the [GetValue<type>(string key)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.getvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-configurationbinder-getvalue-1(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration-system-string)) extension method. You can also use [Index(string key)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationmanager.item?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-configurationmanager-item(system-string)) to return a string. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70392321/276648).

---

You must build a configuration in your main method, get the section and bind it to your model. No way around it.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
        .Build();

    WebProtocolSettings settings_Web = new WebProtocolSettings();
    config.GetSection("WebProtocolSettings").Bind(settings_Web);

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls(settings_Web.Url + ":" + settings_Web.Port)
            .Build()

    host.Run();
}
```

##Update

An alternative way of doing it is by passing the configuration to `UseConfiguration` as described in the

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseKestrel()
        .Configure(app =>
        {
            app.Run(context => 
                context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, World!"));
        })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

or in ASP.NET Core > 2.0

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .Configure(app =>
        {
            app.Run(context => 
                context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, World!"));
        })
        .Build();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tseng, thank you for your answer, however, how do I archive the path for "appsettings.json" in Main Program.cs?

Comment: It has to be in the same folder as the application. Same rules apply when you call it within the startup class

Comment: I found the ways: `.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())`. Also, should be `config.GetSection` not , `Configuration.GetSection`. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Tseng what If you need to access  hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName because you have environment specific hosting.json files?

Comment: Note that when configured this way the configuration won't be updated when the JSON files are changed at runtime. I posted an alternative that works around this.

Comment: To add to the complexity of the question, how does it read the configuration specific to the environment, appsettings-${ENVIRONMENT}.json?

Comment: Will this solution still work when deployed. For example will the app settings in the Json be overridden by the app settings found in the app service?

Comment: @DanCundy: (Azure) App Service values are set via environment variables, so you would have to add `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`. The order of the `AddXxx` is the order in which will be overridden (latest key wins, so what ever is registered last will override previous one - if it has a specific key defined). But these days you have [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for easy bootstrapping of console running services

Answer (score 128):

In .NET 6

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Using the GetValue<type>(string key) method
var configValue = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:CookieAuthentication:LoginPath");

// or using the index property (which always returns a string)
var configValue = builder.Configuration["Authentication:CookieAuthentication:LoginPath"];
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. Should be on the top as most other answers are outdated.

Comment: Which is also written `var configValue = builder.Configuration["Authentication:CookieAuthentication:LoginPath"];`

Answer (score 5):

`.UseConfiguration` (Tseng's alternative answer) is the simplest way, but note that when configured this way changes made to the configuration files at runtime are not applied to your IConfiguration objects. To keep the configuration dynamic you have to use `.ConfigureAppConfiguration` - but then you have to build the configuration an extra time for use in `Main()`. You can re-use the code that configures it, however.

ASP.NET Core 2.2:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationBuilder configBuilderForMain = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        ConfigureConfiguration(configBuilderForMain);
        IConfiguration configForMain = configBuilderForMain.Build();

        // ... use configForMain to read config here ...

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(ConfigureConfiguration)
            // ... the rest of it ...
            .Build();
    }

    public static void ConfigureConfiguration(IConfigurationBuilder config)
    {
        config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In asp.net core 3.1, you can access configuration through the `hostContext`.  This sample is based on the Worker Service Project:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    //Access configuration here with the Host Context.  For example, to get a connection string from AppSettings.json:
                    var connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
```

Comment: ConfigureServises is called AFTER ConfigureWebHostDefaults is called. So this will not help in this case.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

An old question with some new answers, so this is how I like to do it.

1. Define the config in appsettings.json

   ```
        "ServiceConfig": { "PortNumber": 5005 },
   ```
2. Create a class for the config:

   ```
        public class ServiceConfig
        {
            private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
            public const string SectionName = "ServiceConfig";
            public ServiceConfig(IConfiguration config)
            {
                configuration = config;            
                configuration.GetSection(SectionName).Bind(this);            
            }
            public int PortNumber { get; set; }
        }
   ```
3. In Program.cs use the config:

   ```
        var config = new ServiceConfig(builder.Configuration);
        builder.WebHost.UseUrls($"http://*:{config.PortNumber}");
   ```

This method has the added benefit of being able to be used as a service too for dependency injection:

```
         builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceConfig>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The method with the support for command line arguments and default appsettings files:

```
public static class Configuration
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot BuildConfigurationRoot()
    {

        var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        var envArg = Array.IndexOf(args, "--environment");
        var envFromArgs = envArg >= 0 ? args[envArg + 1] : null;

        var aspnetcore = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var dotnetcore = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT");

        var environment = envFromArgs ?? (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aspnetcore)
            ? dotnetcore
            : aspnetcore);

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile(
                $"appsettings.{environment}.json",
                optional: true)
            .Build();

        return configuration; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Might you want to include ".AddEnvironmentVariables()" as a line prior to .Build() ?

Comment: There is a minor error with the `IndexOf()` method.  This method is a static method in the `Array` class.  So instead of `args.IndexOf()`, you need to use the `Array.IndexOf("--environment");`.  An instance of an array cannot be used to access the `IndexOf` static method.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 7 you need to use the `BuildServiceProvider()`

So the top of your `program.cs` will look something like this;

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var _configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
```

And then you can access your `appsettings.json` values like so;

```
var configVal = _configuration.GetSection("Foo").GetValue<string>("Bar");
```

Comment: With the latest package .NET 7 it should be: var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
var configVal = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Foo").GetValue<string>("Bar");

Answer (score 0):

**.NET 8**

Given `appsettings.json` file:

```json
{
  "MySettings": {
    "Name": "Bob",
    "Counter": "100",
  }
}
```

And `MySettings` class:

```cs
public class MySettings
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int? Counter { get; set; }
}
```

Read those values in `Program.cs` file:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var mySettings = new MySettings();
builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection(nameof(MySettings)).Bind(mySettings);

var name = mySettings.Name; // Bob
var counter = mySettings.Counter; // 100
```

Answer (score -3):

In .net core 3.1 you can use ConfigurationHelper.GetConfiguration() to get appSetting variables:

appSettings.json

```
"Endpoint": {
"ip": "170.888.88.888",
"port": 88888}
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     var config = ConfigurationHelper.GetConfiguration();
     var ip = config["Endpoint:ip"];
     var port = config["Endpoint:port"];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where does "ConfigurationHelper" come from? I see some examples of custom classes with this name but behind the scenes they do the same thing as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -4):

Use this code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static string _environmentName;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webHost = BuildWebHost(args);

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        config.ClearProviders();
        _environmentName = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
    }).UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to put the line BuildWebHost(args).Run(); in finish the method Main()