# On click event to update file C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am attempting to create an application which updates a config file.

I have made the following form:

[image]

I have also created the following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DebugOnOrOff
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
                    InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\app.config");
        text = text.Replace("DebugOff", "DebugOn");
        File.WriteAllText("app.config", text);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: and the problem is?

Comment: You are doing it wrong, there are specified ways to update app setting. See the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application) question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllText("app.config", text);
```

Should either be

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\app.config", text);
```

Or

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\app.config", text);
```

As a side note you could also replace this

```
File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\app.config");
```

With

```
File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\app.config");
```

Comment: While technically correct there are better ways for udating application settings.

Answer (score 0):

`File.WriteAllText("app.config", text);`

should be:

`File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\app.config", text);`

Comment: While technically correct there are better ways for udating application settings.