# How to change the relative path programmatic ally for different configuration manager?

Tags: c#

I am currently accessing the File by using the relative path, kindly refer the below code snippet.

```
var filePath = @"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Common\Data";
```

When I build the project with `ANYCPU` it works fine,but when I change the configuration manager to `x64` or `x86` the file cannot be found because in bin folder the `x64/x86` folder is created so that the file cannot be found. However, adding extra dots it works fine. Kindly refer the below snippet.

```
var filePath = @"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Common\Data";
```

Can you please provide the solution that how to detect the configuration manager is `x64/x86` programmatically in `c#`?

Comment: Is the `...Common\Data` part of your solution, or it's independent to the solution?

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your reply the provided path is independent to the solution

Comment: Instead of using the dots, why don't you provide the full path? Since you said it's independent to the solution.

Comment: We can give the entire path but the drive(C: or D:)varies for machine to machine

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 1):

In such case you should consider moving the hard-coded path into config file. e.g.
add below setting in your `app.config` or `web.config`

```
<appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="DataFilePath" value="..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Common\Data" />
    ...
</appSettings>
```

And then load the setting in codes:

```
var filePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataFilePath"];
```

The benefit of this approach is that it give you the flexibility to change the setting after application built. More over you could use the [Web.config Transformation Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) to define specific settings for each build configuration. (Though the example is using `web.config` , this tool actually work for `app.config` as well)

Comment: Hi,I am currently using the Windows forms application i am not using the app.config or web.config file in my sample application.

Comment: you could create a settings-file and add via `Properties.Settings.Default...` - basically the same as shown above

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, like below:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "relativePath");
```