# C# Dynamically added Setting not saved

Tags: c#

I am trying to add settings to Settings file dynamically. I use code below:

```
public PathSourceDir(int id)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _id = id;

    SettingsProperty property = new SettingsProperty(Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["baseSetting"]);

    property.Name = "dynamicSettingName" + _id.ToString();
    property.DefaultValue = _id.ToString();
    Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

    //Read stored value
    var dynamicSetting = Properties.Settings.Default["dynamicSettingName" + _id.ToString()];
}
```

Code runs, however if I comment code lines where new property is created and Settings are saved, and run again, I get an exception:

> System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException: 'The settings
> property 'dynamicSettingName6' was not found.

Meaning that setting previously was not saved in the file. However code was executed before also with id=6. Could you please advise what is wrong?

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["dynamicSettingName" + _id.ToString()]`?

Comment: What is the _exact_ value of `property.Name` (don't guess, check in the `Immediate Window`)?

Comment: Which version of .NET Core / Framework?

Comment: @mjwills `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["dynamicSettingName" + _id.ToString()]` returns null if saving is not performed. property.Name = "dynamicSettingName6". .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: @CreekDrop I'm not very familiar with WinForms but I would recommend referencing these links as I believe you're missing a few things. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/how-can-i-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8