# C# application settings and how to read them

Tags: c#, winforms, application-settings

I want to storen and read a number of settings that the user can change. I followed as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/how-can-i-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application) via the properties of the project, but I saw that there is also a file called "Settings.settings". This file is empty. Is this file not needed? Can I delete it?

Another question I have is how to read the settings. For example I have a setting called "InitialSave" as a boolean. Using this gives the error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'". Can I read direct from the settings or should I declare each setting at startup?

```
Properties.Settings.Default["InitialSave"] == true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You right click this and choose "Open With.. Settings Designer":

[image]

Or you get properties of the project and click Settings on the left. Then you see this:

[image]

You put some settings and types in:

[image]

You write `Properties.Settings.Default.` in code and then you see your settings:

[image]

You can read and write them, as properties of the types you specified

You can even bind them to controls:

[image]

Toggling that control tick state would alter the value of `Proeprties.Settings.Default.IsMinimized`

note: Only User Scoped settings can be changed/saved. App Scope settings are kept in the YourExeName.config file and are changed by editing the file with a text editor. User Scope settings are kept elsewhere (in your user folder) and can be modified and saved at runtime to keep that value for next time the program launches

---

### Edit:

OK, so you said that you can have Settings.settings open in two places; I can't make this occur with the following steps (uses .NET core because Wolle's answer claims core is different; I couldn't support that claim either):

- New project, .NET Core Winforms:

[image]

- Go to project..settings "The project doesn't contain a settings file, click to create one", et voila:

[image]

- Switch to another tab in project properties, for example:

[image]

- Right click/Open with the `settings.settings` file. see this:

[image]

- Try to go back to it in project properties, see this:

[image]

- Add some setting:

[image]

- Access it in the code..

[image]

Comment: Thanks. 
What is the difference then between Settings.settings and the Settings tab under properties of the project?

Comment: No difference at all. indeed if you open it with right click as I describe then try open it via project proeprties youll get an error "This is already open elsewhere"

Comment: Well, that's the thing. That is not the case. I can have Setting.settings open and the settings tab under the properties of the project. Under the properties there is already a DatabaseConnectionString. This is not showing in Settings.settings. So they appear not to be the same.

Comment: Something wonky there. Try it again with a new project. See the edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, @Caius Jard's answer is a little bit outdated, but the go-to way for pre-.NET Core environements.

For the current .NET 5 framework, the most useful source should be the [MSDN docs on configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration).

If you want to store your settings in an file, have a look at the [file configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#file-configuration-provider).

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

// read
var foo = appSettings["bar"];

// write
if (settings[key] == null)  
{  
    settings.Add(key, value);  
}  
else  
{  
    settings[key].Value = value;  
}
```

Comment: Applies to WinForms .NET core too